# Connect a Dell XPS Windows laptop to Ethernet via a generic docking station

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, dell-xps, docking-station

I have a [generic docking station](http://www.gold-touch.net/product/gold-touch-usb-3-0-docking-station/) for laptops. It connects to the laptop with a USB 3.0 connection, and supplies several USB connections plus an Ethernet connection.

When I connected it to a two-years-old laptop -- HP+Ubuntu -- it worked great - I could use Ethernet, mouse, keyboard and printer simultaneously.

Now, I connected it to a new laptop -- Dell XPS 9570 + Windows 10 Pro; all connections I tested work fine (mouse, keyboard and printer) but the ethernet connection is not working - I cannot connect my laptop to ethernet.

Is there something I should do with my laptop so that I can connect it to ethernet via the docking station? Maybe install some driver or change some setting in Windows?

Comment: Your link for the item in your post doesn't take us to anything resembling what you are referring to, but I would troubleshoot this like any other piece of hardware not working. Check Device Manager and look for a device that is not working, and load appropriate drivers. This is most likely a driver issue.

Comment: I would disagree that it doesn't resemble what he's referring to - i think calling the USB things docks is fair, especially now that many 'docks' are single-cable these days (either through USB or a proprietary connector). IMHO, if it has video+USB+Ethernet, I'll call it a dock :D

Comment: Yes, you need drivers for the Ethernet part in Windows. Linux already has support for a lot more network devices than Windows (except some WiFi cards whose manufacturers insist on having proprietary drivers).

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi please post your solution as an answer. Then in 2 days you can mark is as the solution. This helps improve super user, thanks.